# Music major scale converter

Tags: c#

i am trying to create music major scale converter. 
Dose anyone have info how do to it

so far i have

rootNote is scale base note like cMajor or gMajor
note is note that i want to  convert  into major scale 0-126
if i insert rootNote 60  and note 60 the right return would be 0, 
if i insert rootNote 60  and note 61 the right return would be 2,
if i insert rootNote 60  and note 62 the right return would be 4,
if i insert rootNote 60  and note 63 the right return would be 5,

if i insert rootNote 61  and note 60 the right return would be 0, 
if i insert rootNote 61  and note 61 the right return would be 1,
if i insert rootNote 61  and note 62 the right return would be 3,
if i insert rootNote 61  and note 63 the right return would be 5,

ok i have this other one and it seems to work
i want to map my sequence out put in major scale 
but is there some kind of formula what can i use?

.

```
public int getINMajorScale(int note, int rootNote)
    {

            List<int> majorScale = new List<int>();
            //int bNote = (int)_bNote.CurrentValue;

            int bNoteMpl = bNote / 12;
            bNote = 12 + (bNote - (12 * bNoteMpl)) - 7;
            majorScale.Add(bNote + (12 * bNoteMpl));
            int tBnote = bNote;
            int res = 0;
            for (int i = bNote; i < bNote + 6; i++)
            {
                //algorytm
                res = tBnote + 7;
                int mod = 0;
                if (res >= 12)
                {
                    mod = res / 12;
                    res = res - 12 * mod;
                }
                tBnote = res;
                majorScale.Add(res + (bNoteMpl * 12));
            }
            majorScale.Sort();
            int modNuller = 0;
            if (nmr >= 7)
            {
                modNuller = nmr / 7;
                nmr = nmr - 7 * modNuller;
            }
            return (majorScale[nmr] + (modNuller *12));
        }
```

but it's obviously faulty.

Comment: How do you represent a scale?

Comment: What's the definition of `modScaling`? I'm slightly confused as to what you're trying to do. What are `rootNote` and `note`? What units are they; pitch, degree of the scale, position on a piano keyboard?

Comment: note is integral from 0-126 this mean 60 is C4

Comment: We still don't have enough information there. So, say `0 = 'note A'` and `5 = D`, what should `majorScale(0, 5)` do? Should it print an A major scale? In that case what's the second number for? Could you print some sample inputs and outputs so we can see what you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problems with the code as it stands:

- `modScaling` does nothing more than `rootNote % 12` as you always pass in 0 and 11
- You define `mNote` but never use it
- `i` is never used in the `for` loop and so each of the 5 iterations prints the same thing.

---

OK, lets translate your examples into actual notes to make it easier to understand (numbers presumably correspond to [MIDI notes](http://www.harmony-central.com/MIDI/Doc/table2.html)):

- `rootNote = 60` (C), `note = 60` (C) - output 0
- `rootNote = 60` (C), `note = 61` (C#) - output 2
- `rootNote = 60` (C), `note = 62` (D) - output 4
- `rootNote = 60` (C), `note = 63` (D#) - output 5
- `rootNote = 61` (C#), `note = 60` (C) - output 0
- `rootNote = 61` (C#), `note = 61` (C#) - output 1
- `rootNote = 61` (C#), `note = 62` (D) - output 3
- `rootNote = 61` (C#), `note = 63` (D#) - output 5

I might be being really dense but I'm afraid I can't see the pattern there.

A Major scale is of course made up of the sequence Tone, Tone, Semi-tone, Tone, Tone, Tone, Semi-tone, but how does that map to your outputs?

Comment: jes  but there is also other majors compleat map http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MajorScales.svg

Comment: But all major scales follow the same pattern. And that chart doesn't help with the sample outputs you gave. C# (note 61) doesn't feature in a C Major scale, so why should the function return 2 in that case?

Comment: ok  it confuses  me because  major c# is actually minor C?
I am no musician  so forgive me.

Comment: No, C minor is a completely different scale from C# major. A major scale can start on any note and always follows the same pattern of tones and semi-tones. A minor scale can also start on any note but follows a slightly different pattern of tones and semi-tones.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you want to use this function for because it sounds like you've got the wrong idea about what a major scale means.

Answer (score 1):

Given your input-outputs, I think I know what you are looking for.

- determine `steps` = `note - rootNote`
- determine `interval` = number of semi-tones between `rootNote` and the note `steps` up the scale
- determine `phase` = `rootNote - 60`

This algorithm provides accurate results:

```
static int getINMajorScale(int note, int rootNote)
{
    if (note < rootNote) return 0;
    var scale = new[] { 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
    var phase = rootNote - 60;
    var steps = note - rootNote;
    var interval = steps == 0 
        ? 0 : Enumerable.Range(0, steps).Sum(step => scale[step % scale.Length]);
    var number = phase + interval;
    return number;
}
```

yielding:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //rootNote = 60(C), note = 60(C) - output 0
    //rootNote = 60(C), note = 61(C#) - output 2
    //rootNote = 60(C), note = 62(D) - output 4
    //rootNote = 60(C), note = 63(D#) - output 5
    //rootNote = 61(C#), note = 60 (C) - output 0
    //rootNote = 61(C#), note = 61 (C#) - output 1
    //rootNote = 61(C#), note = 62 (D) - output 3
    //rootNote = 61(C#), note = 63 (D#) - output 5

    Console.WriteLine(getINMajorScale(60, 60));  // 0
    Console.WriteLine(getINMajorScale(61, 60));  // 2
    Console.WriteLine(getINMajorScale(62, 60));  // 4
    Console.WriteLine(getINMajorScale(63, 60));  // 5
    Console.WriteLine(getINMajorScale(60, 61));  // 0
    Console.WriteLine(getINMajorScale(61, 61));  // 1
    Console.WriteLine(getINMajorScale(62, 61));  // 3
    Console.WriteLine(getINMajorScale(63, 61));  // 5

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```